# SPARC-RTEMS5-GCC ignores or don't find libraries

Tags: compiler-errors, sparc, rtems

I'm a beginner with RTEMS and I have built a RTEMS5 environment for an erc32 chip (the example in RTEMS Docs) in my computer with
linux mint. The environment comes with sample applications. I'm trying to compile the 
sample from "hello" (init.c) using sparc-rtems5-gcc, here's the command line:

```
sparc-rtems5-gcc -g -O2 /home/michel/masters_project/src/rtems/testsuites/samples/hello/init.c -o /home/michel/masters_project/compile_test/hello2.exe
```

but it returns the following error:

```
fatal error: rtems.h: No such file or directory
 #include <rtems.h>
          ^~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
```

So I tried to comment *rtems.h* in the init.c code and leave the next library of the code,
*tmacros.h*, so I tried to compile again and had the following error:

```
fatal error: tmacros.h: No such file or directory
 #include <tmacros.h>
          ^~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
```

I have used the locate command and found these libraries in the envinronment tree.
As far as I perceived the sparc-rtems5-gcc does not find or ignore the libraries.
I added the bin folder to the PATH variable.
command line:

```
export PATH=$HOME/masters_project/rtems/5/bin:"$PATH"
```

Also I have created the variable
RTEMS_MAKEFILE_PATH based in older versions instructions. I found 
that RTEMS_MAKEFILE_PATH variable should point to where the BSP files are. But
I'm not sure if in the present version of RTEMS it is still necessary to create this environment variable since I have not found any instructions for this in the main docs.

command line:

```
export RTEMS_MAKEFILE_PATH=/home/michel/masters_project/build/b-erc32
```

Could someone help ? Also if you have a working environment could you copy your project
tree for me ?

my uname -a command output:

```
Linux michel-COM 4.15.0-45-generic #48~16.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Tue Jan 29 18:03:48 UTC 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add directory inclusion flags for header file inclusion associated with RTEMS using

- `-I {path-to-RTEMS}`, Example: flag_rtems = -I /opt/rtems/5/, now use `$(flag_rtems)` during compilation stage.
- Exporting `$(PATH)` will help to use the binaries in the run environment not to search the included header files.

Recommended installing RTEMS in `/opt/` directory.

(Note: Directory inclusion flags are used in object file compilation stage, not in linking stage.)